# Protobuf-net on Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I try use Google protobuf in my WP8 application. I use protobuf-net for my purpoces. When I generate my proto.cs file from qwerty.proto I see next string (below)

```
...
[global::System.Serializable, global::ProtoBuf.ProtoContract(Name=@"Query") ]
...
```

But WP8 SDK has not Serializable in System namespace. 
May be I made a mistake when I generated proto.cs via protogen.exe? May be it has any additional parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `protogen -p:help` it will show you the options available *not just for the tool*, but: *for the template you are using* (`csharp` by default). The one of particular interest here is `lightFramework`. So add `-p:lightFramework` and you should be set.

Also: for the best performance on phone 8, you may also want to look at `precompile`, which allows it to use static IL rather than reflection. This is [discussed more here](http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2012/07/introducing-protobuf-net-precompiler.html).

Note that with protobuf-net it is not *required* that you start from a `.proto` file, but that usage is supported; it also works fine "code-first".